# Cycle between elements and change the class to the next one

Tags: javascript, jquery

Is something like this possible?

I have 20 elements with various dynamic classes, but some of them are equal.
Is there a way to move the current class to the next one and so on like this?

Initial

El1 - classA
El2 - classHH
El3 - classKL
El4 - classUI
El3 - classKL
El4 - classYY

to

El1 - classYY
El2 - classA
El3 - classHH
El4 - classKL
El3 - classUI
El4 - classKL

I have been struggling with this for a while and I can't get it right..
I thought about removing and adding the class's while on the loop, but the extra equal classes are bugging me out..

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Can you please provide an example of what you have so far using [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you looking for such kind of behavior:

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  var container = $("ul");
 $("#changeClass").click(function(){
   shiftClasses();
  })
  function shiftClasses(){
   var arrClass = [];
   var allChild = container.children();
    $(allChild).each(function(index,obj){
     var cls = $(obj).attr("class");
     arrClass.push(cls);
      $(obj).removeAttr("class");
    });
    var last = arrClass.pop();
    arrClass.splice(0, 0, last);
    
    $(allChild).each(function(index,obj){
     $(obj).addClass(arrClass[index]);
    });
  }
})
```

```css
.blue{
  background: blue;
}
.red{
  background: red;
}
.yellow{
  background: yellow;
}
.green{
  background: green;
}
ul,li{
  list-style: none;
}
li{
  border: 1px solid black;
  margin-top:20px;
  width:100px;
  height:20px;
  text-align:center;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li class="blue">1</li>
  <li class="red">2</li>
  <li class="yellow">3</li>
  <li class="green">4</li>
</ul>

<button id="changeClass">Shift Class </button>
```